# Mysql trim threm begining of a field up to a designated string

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, substring, trim

I have a mysql database `xxl_wordpress` with a table `wp_posts`
the has a field  `post_content`

`post_content` contains imported HTML pages.

I am trying to remove everything before the `<body>` tag within the content of that field for each record.

Is there an SQL query that will do this? I tried searching for it but was not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following :

```
USE xxl_wordpress
UPDATE `wp_posts`SET `post_content` = MID(`post_content`, locate('<body', `post_content`))
```

Notice I didn't close the body tag. This way if the `<body>` tag has attributes (e.g. `<body class="maintext"`), it will still work.